# JAVAFX - beginner's mistake?

Tags: javafx, treeview

Probably it just a beginner's mistake, but whenever I am trying to create a new FXML project and add this sample code to the main.java (sample was written by Oracle itself to show example, so the code could not be wrong) I got exception error.

BUT! If I delete this line:

```
 private final Node rootIcon =  new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("root.png")));
```

And I don't call a picture to the root, the code runs well! (But just in case I have a root.png next to the .java file)

What could be the reason? I am sure Oracle didn't write a code which is not working.

The code:

import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty;
import javafx.scene.Node;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {
    List<Employee> employees = Arrays.<Employee>asList(
            new Employee("a1", "A"),
            new Employee("a2", "A"),
            new Employee("a3", "A"),
            new Employee("b1", "B"),
            new Employee("b2", "B"),
            new Employee("b3", "B"),
            new Employee("c1", "C"),
            new Employee("c2", "C"),
            new Employee("c3", "C"),
            new Employee("c4", "C"),
            new Employee("e1", "E"));
    private final Node rootIcon =  new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("root.png")));
    TreeItem<String> rootNode = new TreeItem<String>("Root",rootIcon);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        rootNode.setExpanded(true);
        for (Employee employee : employees) {
            TreeItem<String> empLeaf = new TreeItem<String>(employee.getName());
            boolean found = false;
            for (TreeItem<String> depNode : rootNode.getChildren()) {
                if (depNode.getValue().contentEquals(employee.getDepartment())){
                    depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
                    found = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (!found) {
                TreeItem depNode = new TreeItem(employee.getDepartment());
                rootNode.getChildren().add(depNode);
                depNode.getChildren().add(empLeaf);
            }
        }
        stage.setTitle("Tree View Sample");
        VBox box = new VBox();
        final Scene scene = new Scene(box, 400, 300);
        scene.setFill(Color.LIGHTGRAY);

        TreeView<String> treeView = new TreeView<String>(rootNode);
        treeView.setShowRoot(true);
        treeView.setEditable(true);
        box.getChildren().add(treeView);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
    public static class Employee {

        private final SimpleStringProperty name;
        private final SimpleStringProperty department;

        private Employee(String name, String department) {
            this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
            this.department = new SimpleStringProperty(department);
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name.get();
        }

        public void setName(String fName) {
            name.set(fName);
        }

        public String getDepartment() {
            return department.get();
        }

        public void setDepartment(String fName) {
            department.set(fName);
        }
    }
}
```

The exception error:

```
Exception in Application constructor
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.launchApp(Main.java:698)
        at com.javafx.main.Main.main(Main.java:871)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to construct Application instance: class Test
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:393)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.access$000(LauncherImpl.java:47)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl$1.run(LauncherImpl.java:115)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:276)
        ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Input stream must not be null
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.validateInputStream(Image.java:1001)
        at javafx.scene.image.Image.<init>(Image.java:624)
        at Test.<init>(Test.java:29)
        ... 8 more
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: where is `root.png` located?

Comment: package called "test".

 The png is /netbeansprojects/test/src/test/  (Next to the .java file)

Comment: You need to add the package name. `/package name/root.png`

Comment: Thank you so much Itachi! If you write your answer (not just a comment) I'll thumb up! This way every beginner can see the solution easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing the package name while loading the image. Just use the following:

```
new ImageView(new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/packagename/root.png")));
```

This is required, only if, your image is located inside some sub-directory in your classpath.